# Recommendation free code smell detection tool for C++

Tags: linux, c++

I'm looking for a free tool that can detect code smells in C++ source code. Since I use Linux compatibility with gcc or clang would probably be beneficial.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio Code IDE there are many such extensions:

- C-mantic
- C++ Insights
- Cpp Static Checks
- Code Inspector
- Cppcheck Plug-in
- static-analysis
- ReSharper C++
- C/C++ Clang Command Adapter
- Clang-Tidy for VSCode
- Clang Tidy GUI
- Clang-Tidy
- Clang-tidy Linter
- C/C++ Advanced Lint for VS Code

Comment: what about VS OG?